# REST API: What is the recommended URL to expose a Sub-resource of another Sub-resource?

Tags: rest, url, asp.net-web-api2, conceptual

I have two options to expose a *Sub-resource* of another *Sub-resource* but I don't know what approach to go...

Supposing the `people/{parentId}/addresses` endpoint exists (where `people` is the resource and `addresses` is the sub-resource), how should I expose a `customFields` sub-resource of the `addresses` sub-resource?

- **Option 1:** `people/{parentId}/addresses/{subResourceId}/customFields` (third level sub-resource).
- **Option 2:** `addresses/{parentId}/customFields` (sub-resource behaving as a resource).

Is there a preferred way or are both equally right?